# Preventing Redeclared Objects in 2 Scripts

Tags: php, opencart

In building an OpenCart project my client wants to use his own Interspire Email Marketer script located locally on his server.

Both scripts create a database class object, so when trying to include the admin/index.php file from IEM to utilize the PHP API, the get a redeclare error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Db in
>   /home/username/subdomain/public_html/admin/com/ext/database/db.php on
>   line 11

My thought was to build a nice wrapper class in OpenCart and just do all the subscribes and unsubscribes via the wrapper, but it seems this may not be possible.

Is there a way to alias one of the database classes within the wrapper, or am I just going to need to find another way to set this up?

Comment: Is it too complicated to modify those files and rename all the occurrences of `$db` property to something else within them?

Comment: Yeah they're both pretty large programs, renaming them isn't really feasible. I wonder is it possible to do some sort of aliasing when the class is instantiated?

Comment: Maybe it is a silly question, but I don't see a problem when using some good text editor or IDE. Why is it so complicated to hit CTRL + H (or usually it is a command *Edit > Replace*) and replace `$this->db` with `$this->db2` (for example)? And by *program* I guess You mean a *script* (that is a file containing source code, as of *program* is considered to be an executable application compiled from script(s)...).